# What is the best way to switch `filter` function to collect `False` element by using my `switch_var`?

Tags: python, filter, boolean

What is the best way to switch `filter` function to collect `False` element by using my `switch_var`?

I want to

if `switch_var` is `False`, collect tuple first element is `True`.

if `switch_var` is `True`, collect tuple first element is `False`.

Currently I implemented like this.

```
switch_var = False
lst = [(True, "A"), (False, "B")]
if not switch_var:
    filter(lambda x: x[0], lst)
else:
    filter(lambda x: not x[0], lst)
```

but I want the way something like

```
switch_var = True
filter(lambda b: switch_var b, lst)
```

Is there any way like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close. Simply add the `switch_var` boolean in your filter function.

`filter(lambda x: x[0] == not switch_var, lst)`

Answer (score 1):

Alternative [***itertools.filterfalse()***](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.filterfalse) approach:

```
import itertools

switch_var = False
lst = [(True, "A"), (False, "B")]
result = list(itertools.filterfalse(lambda x: x[0] == switch_var, lst))
```